# Nonexistance of collection of 'transformers' that 'trivially modify' Turing machines?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

For a given recursive language $L$, let $TL$ be the language of turing machines that accept $L$, for some encoding of turing machines. $TL$ is countably infinite. Does there exist a set $S = \{S_1,S_2,\cdots\}$ of computable functions that take as input a turing machine and output a turing machine, such that if $T$ is in $TL$ then $S_i(T)$ is also in $T_L$, and that acting the $S_i$ on a given $T$ generates all of $TL$ eventually?

If there exists a set (which probably there isn't), does there exist a finite such set?

The motivation is that the $S_i$ can be thought of as transformations on the space of turing machines that don't change their behaviour, i.e. they are ways to 'rewrite' turing machines, and I wonder if there is a universal collection of such 'rewrite' algorithms. Examples include an $S_i$ that appends an additional, useless, calculation (states) to its input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call such a set "universal transformer".
Yes, there is a universal transformer.

---

Let $\mathcal{ALL}$ be the set of all Turing machines, that is, $\mathcal{ALL}=\{\langle M\rangle\mid M\text{ is a Turing machine}\}$, where $\langle\cdot\rangle$ is some fixed encoding scheme for Turing machines.

By abuse of notation, we will treat an element  $\langle M\rangle$ in $\mathcal{All}$ either as a string or as the Turing machine $M$ that is encoded in that string.

Given two Turing machines $M_1, M_2\in \mathcal{ALL}$, let $\delta_{M_1, M_2}: \mathcal{ALL}\to\mathcal{ALL}$ be such that

- $\delta_{M_1, M_2}(M)=M$ for all $M \not= M_1$.
- if $L(M_1)=L(M_2)$, then $\delta_{M_1, M_2}(M_1)=M_2$. Otherwise $\delta_{M_1, M_2}(M_1)=M_1$.

Note that for all $M$, $L(\delta_{M_1, M_2}(M))=L(M)$. It is easy to check that $\delta_{M_1, M_2}$ is well-defined and computable.

Let $S=\{\delta_{M_1,M_2} \mid M_1, M_2\in \mathcal{ALL}\}$.

Suppose language $L$ is accepted by $T\in\mathcal{ALL}$.

- For any $s\in S$, $s(T)\in TL$.
- If $L(T')=L(T)$, then $\delta_{T,T'}(T)=T'$.

So, $S$ is a universal transformer.

---

Let $L$ be the empty language. $TL$ is the subset of $\mathcal{ALL}$ of all Turing machines that accept no strings.

There are infinitely many Turing machines that accept no strings. For example, the Turing machine $E_i$ that moves left forever after having moved to the right $i$ times.

So, a universal transformer cannot be a finite set.

---

As said above, $S$ is a universal transformer.

However, $S$ is not useful in the sense that $S$ is undecidable. That is, it is not decidable whether we can check a string $s$ is in $S$ or not, assuming that we represent each element in $S$ by some fixed encoding scheme. In fact, $S$ is not computably-enumerable nor co-computably-enumerable.

---

Call a set $S$ "weakly-universal transformer" if given a language $L$ and a Turing machine $T$ such that $T$ accepts $L$, for any Turing machine $T'$ such that $T'$ accepts $L$, there exists a sequence of elements in $S$, $s_1, s_2, \cdots, s_n$ such that $s_n(s_{n-1}(\cdots(s_1(T))\cdots))=T'$.

Claim: A weakly-universal transformer is not computably-enumerable.
Proof: For the sake of contradiction, suppose $S$ is a computably-enumerable weakly-universal transformer. Then the set of all finite sequences of elements in $S$,
$$S^*=\{(s_1, s_2,\cdots, s_n)\mid n\text{ is a positive integer}, s_i\in S \}$$
is also computably-enumerable.

Let $L$ be the empty language. $TL$ is the subset of $\mathcal{ALL}$ of all Turing machines that accept no strings.  Since $S$ is a weakly-universal transformer, $TL=\{q\in S^*\mid q(E_0)\}$, where $E_0$ is the Turing machine that keeps moving left. Since an element in $S$ is a computable function, $TL$ is computably-enumerable. However, we know that $TL$, the language of all Turing machines that accept no strings is not computably-enumerable. This is a contradiction. $\quad\checkmark$

Corollary: A weakly-universal transformer is not finite.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! For your argument that universal transformer cannot be a finite set; I know that $TL$ is infinite, but I had actually meant in my question that *repeated* applications of the $S$ in the universal transformer generates all of $TL$ (in other words, if you label the $S$ as $S_1,S_2,\cdots$, then $S_i(T), S_i (S_j(T)), \cdots$ eventually covers all of $TL$. Is it possible that such a finite set exists?

Comment: My instant bet is No. Let me check.

Comment: @JoshuaLin Please check my update.

Comment: Thank you! What I was missing is that $TL$ for $L$ empty language is not computably enumerable, which I guess comes from Rice's theorem